# How to hide label from a user control in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am struggling to find the solution in hiding the label from the user control when a new form is loaded? So, how do i hide a label from title control in a form ? And title control is loaded as part of the MDI parent...

Comment: It's not clear where the label is, or where the control is. Is the label inside of the user control?

Comment: Why not just create an event when the control loads, that does label.Visible=false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could expose the `Label.Visible` property in a `bool` property of your user control and use it, for sample:

In user control:

```
public bool ShowLabel
{
    get { return Label1.Visible; }
    set { Label1.Visible = value; }
}
```

Using the user control

```
userControl1.ShowLabel = false;
```